# Which districts in the Virginia state legislature held contested primaries for both parties in 2023?

Tags: united-states, parties, primaries, state-legislatures, virginia

In Virginia, there are primaries on June 20th for the state legislature. I am curious about which races are contested for both parties' primaries that are happening on Tuesday, a couple days after I posted this. Which races in the House of Delegates and State Senate are contested by more than 1 candidate in both major party primaries in 2023?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the House of Delegates, just one of the hundred districts is being contested by more than one candidate in both parties' primary elections; [district 84](https://www.vpap.org/offices/house-of-delegates-84/elections/). In the Democratic primary, the district is being contested between Nadarius Clark and Michele Joyce, while the Republican primary is being held between Michael Dillender and Rod Thompson. [District 41](https://www.vpap.org/offices/house-of-delegates-41/elections/) would have been competitive for both parties, however James Harder withdrew from the Democratic primary, leaving Lily Franklin as the sole Democratic candidate.

In the Senate, three districts have contested primaries for both parties; [district 18](https://www.vpap.org/offices/state-senate-18/elections/), [district 27](https://www.vpap.org/offices/state-senate-27/elections/), and [district 29](https://www.vpap.org/offices/state-senate-29/elections/). The [firehouse primary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firehouse_primary) for the Republican Party in district 18 has already taken place - on June 10th.

Comment: For completeness, there are 40 state senate districts in VA which unlike the U.S. Senate (which elects a part of its members every two years), elects all of its members all at once every four years (absent vacancy elections). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virginia_Senate So, 7.5% of Senate seats and 1% of House seats had dual contested primaries in 2023.